# How to Join Tables with Empty Rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you return all rows from Table A, if you joined Table B, Table C, etc and each table joined may not have a matching record?

Example:

```
Table A         Table B         Table C 
Row Letter      Row Shelter     Row Food
1   A           1   House       1   Bread
2   B           2   Shed        2   Cheese
3   C           3   Tent        3   Meat
4   D           4   Patio           
5   E
```

Results

```
Row Letter  Shelter Food                
1   A       House   Bread               
2   B       Shed    Cheese              
3   C       Tent    Meat                
4   D       Patio                   
5   E
```

My query reduces the results based on each table that does not have a matching value, meaning no entry exists for that item.

Comment: check what is left join / right join

Answer (score 0):

Use `Outer Joins`

```
select * 
From TableA a
Left Join TableB b on a.Row = b.Row
Left Join TableC c on a.Row = c.Row
```

Left Join will bring all the records from left table even though there is no matching record present in right table